# Image flickering when navigate to new page

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

When I navigate from extended splashscreen to First page, the image on this page is flickering. Is it normal, because XAML renders asynchronously, or is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May be due to heavy XAML it is flickering. Here is one optimization tips for xaml, please look into [this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/07/optimizing-your-xaml-app-for-performance-10-by-10/)

Comment: I don't think so. I've tried to render only image on page and it flickers.